# Delete project from Netbeans list

Tags: netbeans, ide

Opening Netbeans IDE, it tries to scan the project in "Projects" window. For some reason the scan cannot be done and it freezes Netbeans.

How can I retrieve this project from the "Projects" list without opening the IDE, in the file system of Netbeans.

Thank you.

Note : windows environment, in an xml file maybe

Answer (score 2):

Look for `openProjectsDisplayNames` and `openProjectsURLs` in the file `config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties` in the user configuration directory (see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir )

Delete the ones corresponding to the project you want to avoid opening.

Another option would be to just delete the whole user configuration directory to reset your config. This might be necessary anyway if Netbeans is freezing for another reason.

Comment: and to delete the whole user configuration... where do I go ?

Comment: I cannot find this file... Maybe I have to add that I am using the 7.4 version of Netbeans

Comment: The link should describe where the user configuration directory is depending on your OS version and Netbeans version so you can delete it.